# Unit testing of Spring Boot Actuator endpoints not working when specifying a port

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-actuator

recently I changed my spring boot properties to define a management port.
In doing so, my unit tests started to fail :(

I wrote a unit test that tested the **/metrics** endpoint as follows:

```
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest
public class MetricsTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    /**
     * Called before each test.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.context.getBean(MetricsEndpoint.class).setEnabled(true);
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    /**
     * Test for home page.
     *
     * @throws Exception On failure.
     */
    @Test
    public void home()
            throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/metrics"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Previously this was passing.  After adding:

```
management.port=9001
```

The tests started failing with:

```
home Failed: java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected: <200> but was: <404>
```

I tried changing the @SpringBootTest annotation with:

```
@SpringBootTest (properties = {"management.port=<server.port>"})
```

Where  is the number used for the server.port.  This didn't seem to make any difference.

So then changed the management.port value in the property file to be the same as the server.port.  Same result.

The only way to get the test to work is remove the management.port from the property file.

Any suggestions/thoughts ?

Thanks

Comment: So adding some tracing logging for the success and failing cases.  In the success case I see the following:  
`TRACE [Test worker] --- org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet: Testing handler map [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping@2281521a] in DispatcherServlet with name `  
  
This is missing in the failing case..  So I can only assume that I'm using the wrong value for   

`MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)`

Answer (score 5):

For Spring Boot 2.x the integration tests configuration could be simplified.

For example simple custom `heartbeat` endpoint

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "heartbeat")
public class HeartbeatEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public String heartbeat() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Where integration test for this endpoint

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = HeartbeatEndpointTest.Config.class,
        properties = {
                "management.endpoint.heartbeat.enabled=true",
                "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=heartbeat"
        })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class HeartbeatEndpointTest {

    private static final String ENDPOINT_PATH = "/actuator/heartbeat";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testHeartbeat() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(get(ENDPOINT_PATH))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(""));
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(ProcessorTestConfig.class)
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public HeartbeatEndpoint heartbeatEndpoint() {
            return new HeartbeatEndpoint();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. How can i add a negative use case?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try adding the following annotation to your test class?

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"management.port=0"})
```

[Check the following link for reference](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/#_test_your_application).

Answer (score 4):

For Spring boot test we need to specify the port it needs to connect to.

By default, it connects to `server.port` which in case of actuators is different.

This can be done by

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "server.port=8090")
```

---

in `application.properties` we specify the management port as below

```
...
management.server.port=8090
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't there an error in the property name?
Shouldn't be
`@TestPropertySource(properties = {"management.server.port=..."})` instead of  `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"management.port=.."})`

Answer (score 3):

The guide stated that this can be achieved with @AutoConfigureMetrics.
And I moved with this.

> Regardless of your classpath, meter registries, except the in-memory backed, are not auto-configured when using @SpringBootTest.
> If you need to export metrics to a different backend as part of an integration test, annotate it with @AutoConfigureMetrics.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.metrics

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"management.port="})
```

Properties defined in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation have a [higher precedence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) than those in application properties. `"management.port="` will "unset" the `management.port` property.
This way you don't have to worry about configuring the port in your tests.

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, you just have to make the management.port null by adding this in your application-test.properties (set it to empty value)

```
management.port=
```

Make sure you use the test profile in your JUnit by annotating the class with

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and tried several things but this is how I was able to solve mine without making any change in the `application.yaml`

Sample actuator endpoint

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "endpoint")
public class SampleEndpoint
{
    @GetMapping
    public String sampleEndpoint(){
      return ""
    }
}
```

Unit test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {SampleEndpointTest.Config.class},
    properties = {"management.server.port="}
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SampleEndpointTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {SampleEndpoint.class})
    public static class Config
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSampleEndpoint() throws Exception
    {

        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/actuator/enpoint").accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Comment: this worked for me, running actuator on the same port as the normal endpoints for the test. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently, and as none of the above answers made any sense to me, I decided to do a bit more reading. In my case, I had already defined both `server.port` and `management.server.port` as `8091` in my test `application-test.yaml` file, and could not understand why my test was getting a `connection refused` error message.

It turns out that instead of using the annotation `@SpringBootTest()` I needed to use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)` - which causes the port numbers in the yaml file to be used. This is briefly discussed in the [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html). Quoting the relevant section:

> DEFINED_PORT — Loads an EmbeddedWebApplicationContext and provides a real servlet environment. Embedded servlet containers are started and listening on a defined port (i.e from your application.properties or on the default port 8080).

It seems in `SpringBootTest` the default is to avoid starting a real servlet environment, and if no `WebEnvironment` is explicitly specified then `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK` is used as a default.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search: There is this nice Springboot annotation called `@LocalManagementPort`!

It works similar to `@LocalServerPort` but for actuator endpoins.

An example config would look as follows

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MetricsIT {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @LocalManagementPort
    int managementPort;

    @Test
    public void testMetrics(){
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplateBuilder
            .rootUri("http://localhost:" + managementPort + "/actuator")
            .build().exchange("/metrics", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(null), String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This one failed for me with error 
```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : "{"timestamp":"2023-05-31T22:09:49.535+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/actuator/metrics"}"

```

Answer (score 0):

Since now info endpoint must be enabled manually make sure the SpringBootTest tag includes this in properties, like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        properties = {
                "management.info.env.enabled=true" ,
                "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health"
        })
```