# How to implement test to check that actuator metrics are exist ? 404 for /actuator/prometheus in tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-actuator, spring-resttemplate

I have a spring boot appication(version is 3.0.4):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

In `application.yaml` of application(`src/main/resources`) I have following config:

```
   ....
    management:
      server:
        port: 8081
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: health,prometheus,info
      endpoint:
        info:
          enabled: true
        health:
          enabled: true
          probes:
            enabled: true
          show-details: always
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
      ...
```

When I run application and access url `localhost:8081/actuator/prometheus` in my browser I see a long list of metrics and **it is expected**

Now I want to implement test to make sure that prometheus metrics are available:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class ActuatorTests {
    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @LocalManagementPort
    private int managementPort;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/actuator/prometheus", String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, forEntity.getStatusCode());

    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        ResponseEntity<String> actuatorResponse = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:" + managementPort + "/actuator/prometheus", String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, actuatorResponse.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Both tests are failed with the same error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :200 OK
Actual   :404 NOT_FOUND
```

How can I fix it ?

P.S.

ALso I tried to copy this test as is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334796/2674303

but result is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : "{"timestamp":"2023-05-31T22:09:49.535+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/actuator/metrics"}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config in test configuration fixes the issue:

```
management:
  prometheus:
    metrics.export.enabled: true
```

The tricky thing that this option is not needed in applicaton(because default value is true).

```
package org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.prometheus;
...
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "management.prometheus.metrics.export")
public class PrometheusProperties {

    /**
     * Whether exporting of metrics to this backend is enabled.
     */
    private boolean enabled = true;     
    ...
```

I wasn't able to find a place but looks like some spring boot test starter overwrite this default value. Not sure if this test has a value in case when I need to change configuration to make it working.